# Error compiling hello world program C with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a hello world program in C on a Linux 64-bit machine. I am using an ARM cross compiler to load my application onto an ARM processor. However, when compiling the code using `arm-none-eabi-gcc -o hello hello.c` I get a series of errors:

> /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
>   exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to`_exit'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
>   sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to`_sbrk'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
>   writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x20): undefined reference to`_write'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
>   closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to`_close'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
>   fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x1c): undefined reference to`_fstat'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
>   isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to`_isatty'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
>   lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x20): undefined reference to`_lseek'
>   /home/dico/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
>   readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x20): undefined reference to`_read'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

When I try compiling by doing: `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c hello.c`, it creates an object code `hello.o` which tells me that the compiler runs fine.

Could someone perhaps tell me why my compilation is return such errors please?

**UPDATE**

I realize now that the C runtime library isn't included in the compilation. Does anyone know of any options I need to include in the compilation or how to link the library to be able to use standard functions such as printf for example?

Comment: look http://embdev.net/topic/129753

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235748/linker-error-on-a-c-project-using-eclipse

Comment: It lacks you the libc low level functions. It is platform dependent so the arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain won't have it. It is usually provided by the chip manufacturer. What is the target platform ? **If** you stop using libc functions (printf, malloc, open, etc.) you may compile your program.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @fanl my target platform is a FOX G20 V with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor. I need to compile the hello world program (hence use printf, return etc), but this is to test the compilation. Later, I will use a standard library for my source code (uIP). Do you how I can compile the hello world program then?

Comment: Do I have to add an option or any options in the command line when compiling?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, basically you should have a .c file (usually called retarget.c or syscalls.c) defining what libc should do with printf outputs for example. Printf builds a string, where should this string go inside the MCU chip since there is no console. Did you get it now? Usually retarget.c sends the printf outputs to a serial line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should the MCU chip do with a printf string since there is no console? That's what is happening. libc needs low level functions that is platform dependent and shall not be included in the libc.

You need a retarget.c or a syscalls.c file that defines all these missing symbols and properly retarget the printf output to a serial line that you have access from the outside of the chip.

I strongly recommend you to use the [yagarto](http://www.yagarto.org) toolkit, they provide a [syscall.c](http://www.yagarto.de/download/yagarto/syscalls.c) file with what's necessary to build a project when linking against libc, as you are doing.

If you want to try the short path, include the [syscall.c](http://www.yagarto.de/download/yagarto/syscalls.c) file to your project and reprogram its functions internals to suit your needs.

Linking bare gcc toolchain against libc in the microcontroller world is not for beginners. My recommendation is always to follow step by step yagarto's tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This hello world program and hence the use of print is just to test the toolchain for later use in my project. Once I can hopefully get it to work, I will no longer use these standard functions but will rather use a standard library (uIP). Although, your syscall.c link doesn't work.