# __isr_vectors variable not found when placed inside a static library

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, static-libraries, linker-scripts

As a spin-off of a previous question ([sbrk function not found when placed in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895703/sbrk-function-not-found-when-placed-in-a-static-library)):
I'm creating a bare-metal application for the stm32f407 microcontroller, which has an ARM Cortex M4 core. I'm trying to create a static library containing basic stuff like cmsis, the HAL functions, and the interrupt vector table, and link that static library to my main application. However, when the interrupt vector table (which is a variable named `__isr_vectors`) is placed inside the static library, the variable does not survive linking.

I can piece together what happens: The linker has an object main.o, and a few libraries. It takes all symbols found in `main.o`, and it takes all symbols out of the libraries that are used by `main.o` or that are used by other symbols that are already deemed necessary. The `__isr_vectors` variable is not yet needed at this stage, since no one references this variable explicitly, so it is thrown out by the linker. Then, the linker searches for all input sections named `.isr_vector` in order to create the output section `.isr_vector`. However, no symbols survived up to this moment, so that output section is left empty, and my binary is left without an interrupt table.

I know of one trick to get the `__isr_vector` to survive: reference it in a dummy function in `main.c`. However, this is kinda ugly and error-prone (you can forget to do that when building a new application against the same static library). So here's my question: Is there another way to make the `__isr_vector` survive, so that I can just link in my static library and be done with it?

These are the files and steps to reproduce the problem:

vectors.c:

> __ attribute__ ((section(".isr_vector"), used)) void* __isr_vectors = 0;

main.c:

> void _start(void) {}

link.ld:

> MEMORY
>      {
>        FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
>      }
>
> ENTRY(_start)
>
> SECTIONS
>      {
>          .isr_vector : ALIGN(4)
>          {
>              KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
>          } >FLASH
>
> ```
>    .text : ALIGN(4)
>    {
>        *(.text .text.*)
>    } >FLASH
> ```
>
> }

Commands:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2014q4\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -ffunction-sections -std=gnu11 -o main.c.obj -c main.c
>      "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2014q4\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -ffunction-sections -std=gnu11 -o vectors.c.obj -c vectors.c
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2014q4\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -ffunction-sections -std=gnu11 -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -Wl,-Tlink.ld -Wl,-Map=test_linker.without_library.map main.c.obj vectors.c.obj -o test_linker.without_library.elf
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2014q4\bin\arm-none-eabi-ar.exe cq libtest_linker.lib.a vectors.c.obj
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2014q4\bin\arm-none-eabi-ranlib.exe" libtest_linker.lib.a
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2014q4\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -ffunction-sections -std=gnu11 -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -Wl,-Tlink.ld -Wl,-Map=test_linker.with_library.map main.c.obj -o test_linker.with_library.elf libtest_linker.lib.a

Comment: You have `--gc-sections`. Have you tried a `used` attribute on the `__isr_vectors` variable and/or a `KEEP` statement for the `.isr_vector` section in the linker script?

Comment: The variable already has the `used` attribute, it is declared like this:

`__attribute__ ((section(".isr_vector"),used))
pHandler __isr_vectors[] =`

The linker file already has the KEEP statement, and looks like this:

`KEEP(*(.isr_vector))`

Still, the variable is thrown away

Comment: I cannot reproduce, it seems to work for me. Could you put all things together (Makefile, startup, linker script minimal main program) and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I have uploaded a .rar file via wetransfer: http://we.tl/xfVcTvHkkL . This file contains a Compile.cmd which issues 6 commands with which both versions are compiled and linked. Afterwards, you can compare the two .map files and see that one of them is missing the __isr_vectors variable. For compilation, I used the GNU ARM executables from here: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2014-q4-major .

Comment: When I try to extract files from that archive, only main.c succeeds. rar is not free, so my Linux client might be too old. Zip file?

Comment: Ah, ok, no problem. Zip file is available here: http://weshare.me/09e046de108ebfd5/link_discards_vectors.zip

Comment: Tough problem ... but now it seems to work, see my answer. Anyway could you please paste the files in the zip archive directly into the question? Otherwise nobody else can benefit from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this problem in the same kind of environment (arm-none-eabi-gcc-cs-5.2.0-3.fc23.x86_64, arm-none-eabi-binutils-cs-2.25-2.fc23.x86_64 on Fedora 23).

It seems the linker does not try to read content of the archive as it has already all the symbols it needs. it's probably a kind of optimization or a bug.

An alternative solution to force the archive to be read for "used" symbols, is to force the linker ld to consider __isr_vectors as undefined, with `-u __isr_vectors`.

As gcc option, `-Xlinker -u -Xlinker __isr_vectors` or `-Wl,-u,__isr_vectors`.

Comment: And similarly, I found this can be accomplished by using EXTERN(__isr_vectors) in the linker file.

Answer (score 4):

I have made two changes to your files:

In the linker script, I have changed the `ENTRY` from

```
ENTRY(_start)
```

to

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
```

and in vectors.c I have added this function:

```
void Reset_Handler(void) {
}
```

The trick is that `Reset_Handler` is a function in the translation unit `vectors.c` wheras `_start` is somewhere else.

Now when `Reset_Handler` is linked in (enforced by `ENTRY`), `__isr_vectors` seems to be considered as well! So it seems that another function in that translation unit must be linked in order to "drag along" that variable.

---

For completeness sake:

- Normally the `Reset_Handler` is referenced in the `__isr_vectors`, and `Reset_Handler` calls `main` eventually (in your case it's `_start`). So this is not just a workaround, you probably need that anyway.
- I have added `-fdata-sections` to the compile commands

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a follow-on to the posted answer:
I suggest that you only need to change the ENTRY in the linker script to:
ENTRY(g_pfnVectors)
I submit that this is less work, and does not require change to the original source file.
If g_pfnVectors does not exist in your source file, it is the name of the vector table itself in our file.  Modify as appropriate.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that although it results in a correct executable, when loading this application in the debugger the debugger tries to start execution at g_pfnVectors.

Comment: Depending on the IDE and the debugger, you can "tell" the debugger where to start.  "*g_pfnVectors" or somesuch would work well.