# Function pointer in struct not working?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, undefined-reference, atmelstudio

I have a driver and code that works on IAR but does not work for Atmel Studio 7.  I get an error `ld returned 1 exit status` and `undefined reference to '_read'` (or `_write`) when I try to assign a function to a pointer inside a struct.

In the driver that I need to use there are two pointers defined as follows:

```
#define BMM050_WR_FUNC_PTR \
    s8 (*bus_write)(u8, u8, \
    u8 *, u8)

#define BMM050_RD_FUNC_PTR \
    s8 (*bus_read)(u8, u8, \
    u8 *, u8)re
```

In the file they have a struct defined as follows:

```
struct bmm050_t {
    u8 company_id;/**<mag chip id*/
    u8 dev_addr;/**<mag device address*/

    BMM050_WR_FUNC_PTR;/**< bus write function pointer*/
    BMM050_RD_FUNC_PTR;/**< bus read function pointer*/
    void (*delay_msec)(BMM050_MDELAY_DATA_TYPE);/**< delay function pointer*/

    s8 dig_x1;/**< trim x1 data */
    s8 dig_y1;/**< trim y1 data */

    s8 dig_x2;/**< trim x2 data */
    s8 dig_y2;/**< trim y2 data */

    u16 dig_z1;/**< trim z1 data */
    s16 dig_z2;/**< trim z2 data */
    s16 dig_z3;/**< trim z3 data */
    s16 dig_z4;/**< trim z4 data */

    u8 dig_xy1;/**< trim xy1 data */
    s8 dig_xy2;/**< trim xy2 data */

    u16 dig_xyz1;/**< trim xyz1 data */
};
```

In my application I try to do:

```
bmm050.bus_write = i2c_write;
bmm050.bus_read = i2c_read;
```

My functions are defined as:

```
int8_t i2c_write(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count);

int8_t i2c_read(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count);
```

EDIT: I am attaching the error code as asked:

```
c:/program files (x86)/atmel/studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
C:\Users\aba\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Project1\Project1\Debug\writer.c(1,1): error: undefined reference to `_write'
c:/program files (x86)/atmel/studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
C:\Users\aba\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Project1\Project1\Debug\readr.c(1,1): error: undefined reference to `_read'
collect2.exe(0,0): error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: use a debugger, get a dump, backtrace and all that, and have a look at what `BMM050_MDELAY_DATA_TYPE` actually is.

Comment: None of the code you've shown has any mention of `_read` and `_write` (only `bus_read` or `i2c_read` etc.). What makes you think the linker is complaining about this code?

Comment: I commented those the two lines where I try to assign functions and errors disappear.

`BMM050_MDELAY_DATA_TYPE` is a `uint_32t` and for some reason doing bmm050.delay_msec = delay_cycles_ms works fine

Comment: For the love of obfuscation, use `typedef` and not icky macros!

Comment: You have a great point, but this comes from fully written driver which I would prefer not to change. I tried rewriting it using `typedef`, however, as they use these macros everywhere in the code I would need to change it everywhere as well...

Comment: Whilst looking online I found that many people associate this problem to linker. Is there a chance that is the case?

Comment: As far as I can see, to be complaining about `_read` (instead of, say, `bus_read`) then either there's a cut-and-paste error in the code you're showing (e.g. the 2nd macro definition has a trailing `re`) or some other macro-stuff is kicking in (you haven't got `i2c` defined as an empty string somewhere? ... stray spaces in your assignment statements?).

Comment: Please cut and paste the full "ld" and "undefined" error messages verbatim into the question (as code).

Comment: Please find it added.

Comment: Your error messages and the snippets of code you posted here seem completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your `i2c_write` and `i2c_read` functions call `printf`, `write`, `putc`, `puts`, or a similar function.  Yes?

The errors you are seeing are the wrappers `_write_r` and `_read_r` trying to invoke the underlying `write` and `read` functions, and not being able to find them.  See, e.g., [this discussion (sec. 6.4)](http://www.billgatliff.com/newlib.html) of implementation of these functions in [the newlib C library](https://sourceware.org/newlib/).

The errors disappear when you comment out the `bmm050.bus_write = i2c_write` and `bmm050.bus_read = i2c_read` lines because nothing else in your code calls `read` or `write`.  If you don't reference `i2c_read` in your code, such as when those lines are commented out, the linker can remove `i2c_read` from the compiled object file.  Without `i2c_read`, there is no need for `_read_r` or `read`, so you don't get the linker errors.

**So what to do?**

A few options, in the order I would try them.

1. Call your board-support-package (BSP) vendor if you have a support contract.
2. Search through the Atmel Studio source/libraries to see if they provide a `_read` or `_write` implementation for your particular hardware.  If Atmel Studio includes a BSP for your board, that may include the functions.  (I don't have Atmel Studio myself, and probably wouldn't have the same BSP even if I did, so I can't tell you more specifically than that where to look.)

   - **Note** that those functions may be called `read()` and `write()` (without the leading underscore) if they are written in C.  C compilers generally [add a leading underscore to exported names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628384/2877364).
3. Modify your `i2c_read` and `i2c_write` so they access the device's I2C registers directly.  If you can eliminate calls the C library's I/O routines from those functions, you will no longer need `_read` or `_write`.
4. If you can't find an existing implementation or eliminate the need for one, look online for implementations.  For example, [this blog post](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/351044#3903058) (in German) includes a sample implementation of `_write`.  That, plus the links below it in the thread, may help you (even if you don't speak German).
5. Finally, if necessary, roll your own `_read` and `_write` that will do some meaningful input and output on your particular target.  I gather that's I2C, but you might at some point want that to be UART, LCD, seven-segment display, Nixie, or something else — write whatever I/O routines you wish!  Note that this basically involves the same type of work as #3, but in a different context.

See also:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237079/2877364), which relates to a similar situation on a different platform
- [this discussion](http://www.openhardware.net/Embedded_ARM/NewLib_Stubs/) of implementing your own OS (effectively) in order for `_write_r` to have something to talk to!