# CMake linker "undefined reference" when switching from gcc to g++ for cross compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cmake, cross-compiling

I have a C project which compiles successfully. Now I want to use C++ code in the same project, so I renamed `main.c` to `main.cpp`. The project is for an embedded microcontroller, so I'm cross compiling with the `arm-none-eabi` toolchain.

When I have renamed the main file to .cpp, I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable discovery_simple_test.elf
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/<long_path>/fpu/libg.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
/build/<long_path>/newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to `_exit'
```

This is because some standard libraries are not available for this "bare metal" target. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237079/507369)

This is solved in my linker script:

```
/* Remove information from the standard libraries */
/DISCARD/ :
{
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
}
```

The linker script is added by my CMake toolchain file:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-g++ GNU)

SET(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F407VGTx_FLASH.ld)
SET(COMMON_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0")
UNSET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CACHE)
UNSET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS CACHE)
UNSET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS CACHE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=c++11" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=gnu99" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
project(discovery_simple_test CXX C ASM)
add_definitions(-DSTM32F407xx)

file(GLOB_RECURSE USER_SOURCES "Src/*.c" "Src/*.cpp")
include_directories(Inc)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${USER_SOURCES}  ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.map")
```

When linking as a C executable, this works. When linking as a C++ executable I get the `undefined reference` error.

### Update

I looked at the exact linker commands composed by CMake and those are:

For GCC (successful):

```
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork 
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
-g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99  -Wl,-gc-sections 
-T /path/STM32F407VGTx_FLASH.ld -Wl,
-Map=/path/build/discovery_simple_test.map 
CMakeFiles/discovery_simple_test.elf.dir/Src/main.c.obj 
<list of obj files>  
-o discovery_simple_test.elf libCMSIS.a
```

For G++ (Error):

```
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork 
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
-g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11  -Wl,-gc-sections 
-T /home/niels/Dev/stm32/discovery_simple_test/STM32F407VGTx_FLASH.ld 
-Wl
-Map=/path/discovery_simple_test/build/discovery_simple_test.map 
CMakeFiles/discovery_simple_test.elf.dir/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c.obj 
CMakeFiles/discovery_simple_test.elf.dir/Src/stm32f4xx_it.c.obj   
CMakeFiles/discovery_simple_test.elf.dir/Src/main.cpp.obj 
<List of obj files>
-o discovery_simple_test.elf libCMSIS.a
```

So at least the parameters passed to g++ are the ones I expected. I tried removing --gc-sections in combination with adding -nostartfiles, but this didn't help.

Comment: This problem perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877437/undefined-reference-to-errors-when-linking-static-c-library-with-c-code/18879053#18879053

Comment: Thank you πάντα ῥεῖ, I checked but all header files which are included in main.cpp, already have the code wrapped in "extern C".

Comment: Is this really a CMake problem or is it related to C and C++?

Comment: @usr1234567 I don't know. In the end it is a C(++) linker problem, but it probably needs to be fixed at CMake level.

Comment: @i.amniels Sure, but you have to figure out the flags/includes without CMake and then add them to your CMake files. But your issue is not caused by CMake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing functions have to provide the interface between newlib and the hardware or the OS, these are called the `system calls`.

The linking issue can be solved by adding the `--specs=nosys.specs` command line option as stated by user Cinder Biscuits. This option provides mostly non-functional implementations of the system calls.

But this only solves the linking issue, if functionality from newlib is actually required, an implementation of the system calls needs to be provided.

A guide for developing the system calls can be found [here](http://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean9/ean9-howto-newlib-1.0.html#sec_syscalls).

For the STM32 microcontrollers, ST provides a file `syscalls.c` as part of their [STM32CubeF4](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef4.html) software package. The file can be found in the package at `Projects/STM32F4-Discovery/Examples/BSP/SW4STM32/`. By adding this file to the project, implementations for all the syscalls are provided and newlib can be used.

For a small microcontroller like the STM32, newlib nano should be used as it is much smaller. This can be achieved by adding the `--specs=nano.specs` command line parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a more CMakeish way to do this, but try adding `-specs=nosys.specs` your CMake toolchain file like so:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-specs=nosys.specs, -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

"nosys" is generic implementation for barebone systems.

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/170926122/readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

> Linking CXX executable discovery_simple_test.elf
>   /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi//fpu/libg.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
>   /build/<long_path>/newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to`_exit'

The `_exit` function is part of *newlib* (check `newlib/_exit.c` ). Try adding following flag to the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`: **`--specs=nano.specs`**

As you are on a freestanding system it makes also sense to add **`-ffreestanding`** to both – C and C++ – compiler flags.